# Copy rows with Qty>0

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I would like to create an Excel formula (without using VBA) to fill a sheet named "Bill" based on another sheet named "Prescription".

I have for example 10 rows in the sheet "Prescription" with columns Title, Quantity, Price and Total. I want to copy the rows where Quantity>0 to the sheet "Bill" without having any blank rows.

I know it is easy to do with VBA, all I have to do is to copy every rows (including blank rows), set up an autofilter to hide 0s and then add some VBA to refresh the filter, but I'm pretty sure I could do it without VBA (maybe with an array-formula or something to get the Nth non-0 value).

So this is "Prescription":

```
Title|Qty|Price| Total
----------------------
Test1|  0|99.99|     0
Test2|  1|99.99| 99.99
Test3|  0|99.99|     0
Test4|  3|99.99|299.97
```

I want a formula to get in another sheet:

```
Title|Qty|Price| Total
----------------------
Test2|  1|99.99| 99.99
Test4|  3|99.99|299.97
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an array-formula that does the job from Microsoft KB database:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/101167

The final formula:

```
={IFERROR(INDEX(Prescription!$I$1:$I$100,SMALL(IF(ISEMPTY(Prescription!$K$1:$K$100),"",ROW(Prescription!$K$1:$K$100)),ROW(2:2))-ROW(Prescription!$K$1:$K$100)+1),"")}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about MS Query?:

```
SELECT * FROM [Prescription$] AS S WHERE S.Qty> 0
```

Use Data->Get External Data->MS Query or u can also you a simple Add-In I made: 
http://blog.tkacprow.pl/excel-tools/excel-sql-add-in-free/

Once you execute the query once you can refresh it at any time by right-clicking and hitting refresh on the Query Table.

Comment: I would like Excel to update it automatically (which is the advatange of using Excel formulas). I will take a look further into SQL though since I didn't even know this was possible in Excel. Please also note that I'm in a business environment and may not be able to activate add-ins.

Comment: Sure. I am sure you can do this using formulas but it will be more complicated. You can also try Pivot Tables with filtering. As for the Add-In - xlam Add-Ins should work in a business env (their a simply Excel files without visible worksheets). Anyway the file can be opened to see the actual code without enabling it. I usually go for SQL because it is very easy and concise compared to writing complicated formulas.